# Debian etch source list

Tags: apt, debian-lenny, debian-etch

I've an webserver that is still debian etch.

My problem is I need to upgrade some packages but I can't find a source for debian etch anywhere.

I have the following:

```
###### Debian Main Repos
deb http://ftp.ie.debian.org/debian/ etch main
deb-src http://ftp.ie.debian.org/debian/ etch main

deb http://security.debian.org/ etch/updates main contrib
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ etch/updates main contrib
```

but my main repos don't seem to exist anymore.

I know I need to upgrade to lenny but the docs recommend you update to latest etch first before doing a dist-upgrade.  Where can I find the latest etch source?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried the mirrors on the [archive list](http://debian.org/distrib/archive)?

Comment: +1 Updates for *Etch* have been [discontinued as of February 2010](http://www.debian.org/releases/etch/).

Answer (score 3):

try with mirrors from here http://debian.org/distrib/archive